# PyQt Rowspan Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, textbox, pyqt4

I'm working on creating a GUI for an Irish Dictionary searcher using PyQt. I have already completed it in tkinter, but heard that PyQt was just much better and the way to go, so I wanted to work on a version of it, too. I'm almost done, except I'm having an issue. I'm creating a bilingual version, Irish and English, but I want both versions to use the same text widget, so you can see words you've called in either version. However, it wouldn't show up in the second one, even having it added to the rid, so I had to remove/add it in my switch callback. However, after I did that, it's not showing up the correct size, despite multiple settings on rowspan. The relevant code is attached. The grid that appears at startup in the EnglishVersion class works perfectly (though it'd be nice if I could make it a bit bigger since a lot of text is getting presented), but after I switch versions it becomes too small to be useful.

Edit: New code containing only the problem, as requested

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Callback(): 
    def remove():
        foo.hide()
        bar.show()
        foo.layout().removeWidget(foo.text_entry)
        bar.layout().addWidget(bar.text_entry, 1, 0, 24, 2)

class Text(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text_entry = QtGui.QTextEdit(parent)


class Foo(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text_entry = text.text_entry
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Remove and readd text")
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda: Callback.remove())

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.text_entry, 1, 0, 24, 2)
        self.setLayout(grid)


class Bar(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.text_entry = text.text_entry
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("After it has been pushed")
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.button, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(grid)




app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
text = Text()
foo = Foo()
bar = Bar()
foo.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please provide a complete, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Done. Post has been edited containing it without all the other junk.